# EXC_BAD_ADRESS generated after willSelectRowAtIndexPath executed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Why EXC_BAD_ADRESS generated after willSelectRowAtIndexPath executed and before didSelectRowAtIndexPath??
Without willSelectRowAtIndexPath implementation it works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        KMWTableViewCell *cell = (KMWTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(cell){
            cell.visibleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackPressed.png"]];
        }
    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        KMWTableViewCell *cell = (KMWTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(cell){
            [self setCurrentAccountId:[[[KMWAppDelegate accounts] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"accountId"]];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"services" sender:self];
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line does it crash?

Comment: Somewhere between those methods. Not in my code.

Comment: `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should return `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: It is the received parameter, not returning value. The return type is actually void.

Comment: can you post it to answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method signature is wrong. It's return value should be `NSIndexPath`:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KMWTableViewCell *cell = (KMWTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell){
        cell.visibleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackPressed.png"]];
    }

    return indexPath;
}
```

Within your implementation you finally need to return the given `indexPath`.